# PowerShell 3 ExpandString loses text

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm finding that in PowerShell 3, `ExpandString` is truncating my template string and only giving the very beginning of it. This worked in PowerShell 2 without a hitch, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

The goal is to insert the value of `$theSetting` into the template string. Note that I use a regex to escape quotes and graves so that PowerShell doesn't try to expand them, and that appears to be working fine.

```
PS > $theSetting = 'x'
PS > $template = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><AppSettings><Setting value="${theSetting}"/></AppSettings>'
PS > $template = $template -replace "('|`"|``)", '`$1'
PS > $template
<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"utf-8`" ?><AppSettings><Setting value=`"${theSetting}`"/></AppSettings>
PS > $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
<?xml version="
```

For some reason, it's cutting it off after the first double quote. I appreciate any help in identifying what changed between PowerShell 2 and 3.

As you might guess given the template text, I'm actually loading the template from a file and writing the contents back out, and this is being used for configuration files that are far more variable and complex than the sample template seen here. So something simple like a regex instead isn't really an option.

For the benefit of future readers, *don't do this*. Use a real templating engine (e.g., Mustache).

Comment: The template works for me on V3 if I remove the line with the `-replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell 3 changed the way it parses strings to where you no longer need to change the `"` to `` `" ``. I'm not quite sure why it evaluates it as the end of a string though.

Like Keith said, if you remove the replace code you have you will be fine. You can also detect to see if you are running on a lower powershell version and do the replacement like this:

```
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 3) { $var = $var -replace '"','`"' }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This helps immensely. Thank you. What about single quotes and graves? Do either of those still need to be replaced?

Comment: Apologies. I tried it out myself. `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("hello ' single quote")` results in `hello ' single quote`, and ``$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString('hello ` grave')`` results in `hello  grave`. So it looks like graves still need to be escaped and single quotes do not.